# What is the name of the box which keeps software CD?

Tags: vocabulary, proper-nouns

I don't know its exact name or how do you call this box in English:
The CDs inside the box are essential and required to be installed before the paid hardware can fully function.

[image: Cardboard box]

I don't own this box. I found it somewhere on the Internet. I came up with the question, so I typed in some keyword on Google and then I found some photos about boxes that keep software CDs.

---

**Update:**

Thank you, @Usernew and @CookieMonster, for your prompt help.
I am sorry that my question is confusing to most of you. Please let me explain it some more. Say, I bought a sound card of ABC company some time ago, and the sound card was packed in a square cardboard box, and when I opened the square cardboard box, I found a software CD that came with the sound card.

And my question is, what is the name of that cardboard box which keeps that software CD and the sound card?

Comment: CD storage box.

Comment: A box used for keeping CDs would be one thing. "The CDs inside the box are essential and required to be installed before the paid hardware can fully function" would be another, and it's not often that they will come in a box. (Paper jackets would be the usual.) Also, the question makes me wonder what hardware that is. Cookie Monster's suggestion, "CD bundle", is good, though (I upvoted his answer), even though I'm not very sure you're really thinking of that.

Comment: Installation software CDs?

Comment: I don't think there's a special name for it, "Product box" would be fine.

Comment: @kitty That box which keeps the software CD, the Sound Card, and probably some wires, and User Manual is called a "box," "carton," or "product box," or, to be more specific, "Sound Card box". For example, [This](http://www.legitreviews.com/images/reviews/679/geforce_9800gx2_box.jpg) is a Graphic Card box. People usually call it a "box." It doesn't matter what kind of a box, just a box. For smaller boxes, usually food items, we tend to call it "[pack‌​](http://www.get929.com/image/cache/data/drinks/Real%20orange-500x500.png)" rather than "box"

Comment: @kitty I have the same pack of juice in my refrigerator, and it gives a warning on the back that says, "Do not buy if the **pack** is puffed."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different types of packing and packaging layers, kitty.

You can read about the three packaging layers on Wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packaging_and_labeling#Packaging_types).

There are many different packaging for CD/DVDs as well.

Here are [the different packaging styles](http://www.ebay.com/gds/CD-PACKAGING-DIFFERENT-TERMS-WHAT-THEY-MEAN-/10000000004623100/g.html) (thanks to [Rainbowjam](http://stores.ebay.com/rainbowjam) for making my work easier.):

> **Jewel Case:** The normal plastic case with a plastic tray inside which holds the CD. Will include a paper inlay at the back and a paper inlay or booklet at the front. This is the standard packaging for CD albums.
>   **Slipcase:** A cardboard box, open at either one or both ends which slips over the jewel case. Sometimes also holds a thicker booklet which doesn't fit inside the jewel case.
>   **Box Set:** A box which is different to a slipcase as it doesn't have any open ends. Usually used to hold multiple CDs in either jewel cases or card sleeves but occasionally used as special packaging for a single CD. 
>   **Slimline Jewel Case:** A slimmer jewel case to standard with no inner tray; the CD is held in place on the back of the jewel case. Will include a paper inlay at the front with the disc visible at the back. This is the standard packaging for CD singles. 
>   **Wide/Fat Double/Multiple Jewel Case:** A jewel case which is at least twice as deep as a standard jewel case and opens at the back as well as the front to hold 2 or more CDs. Will include paper inlays at the front and back and may have a booklet inside as well. This is the standard packaging for older CD double albums.
>   **Slim Double Jewel Case:** A standard jewel case with a special tray inside. The tray holds a CD on each side and flips open  inside the jewel case like the pages of a book. Will include a paper inlay at the back and a paper inlay or booklet at the front. This is the standard packaging for CD double albums.
>   **Digipak:** A cardboard sleeve which opens up like a book to reveal a plastic tray glued inside which holds the CD. All the CD artwork is printed on the cardboard packaging. May include a booklet which will slot inside the digipak.
>   **Fold-out Digipak:** Exactly the same as above but with extra fold-out sections on the digipak.
>   **Slidepack:** A cardboard slipcase, thinner than those used to hold a jewel case, which holds a plastic tray (similar to the tray inside a digipak) containing the CD. All the CD artwork is printed on the slipcase.
>   **Card Sleeve:** A cardboard sleeve identical to a record cover but in miniature. All the CD artwork is printed on the sleeve.
>   **Plastic Wallet/Sleeve:** A clear thin plastic sleeve with a fold-in envelope style flap. Usually only used for promotional CDs; if you're offered a standard release (ie: not a promo) in this kind of packaging (with or without artwork) then it's probably a pirate copy. Check out my guide on the different types of illegal CDs and how to spot them. Assuming the CD is a promo, it will either have a generic insert (white paper with printed CD details), a picture insert (basic copy of the proposed artwork - usually poorer quality than the finished product) or sometimes no insert at all.

There is one more:

> **CD sleeve:** just like a cardboard sleeve, but there is usually no printing work on the cover, also, it is usually made of paper(or some other material I am unaware of). I think ***this type of packaging is used everywhere when there is a CD inside the box which is essential and required to be installed before the paid hardware can fully function.*** Here it is:

[image]

The big brown coloured box that [Cookiemonster](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/73898/20213) provided is called a **[Carton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carton)** or simply a **box.** I won't call it a shipping box unless I am sure that they are being shipped.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use any special names.  I just call it a box:

> I bought Photoshop a long time ago, and it came in a huge box with a CD and a bunch of manuals.  I put the manuals and CD back in the box after I installed it and kept the box on my shelf.

If I needed to, I'd use a larger phrase like *the box my sound card came in*.  I could also call it something like *packaging*, but I generally don't.

So really, I don't think you need a special term.  You can just say *box*.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure what you're asking about (if you could be just a tad clearer), but what I can tell from looking at the picture you provided is that it looks more like a box for an electronic device, not a CD bundle. A CD bundle would be a bunch of CDs packaged and sold together as a single unit. I guess we could call it a software CD bundle or a CD box set. Something along those lines. Here's a Wikipedia article about different types of optical disc packaging techniques: [Box set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_set). Take your pick.

In computer-speak though, computer programs pre-written on compact disks like that and sold in consumer electronics stores are generally called *shrink-wrapped software*. Here's what this type of packaging looks like:

[image]

For bigger items like a TV set or computer display, I guess *shipping box* is the term we would normally use:

[image]

Let me know if this has been helpful or I got something wrong.

Comment: Your Dell box makes me think of another term, *original box* (or *original package/packaging*), which could be the case if the OP wants to buy something on eBay, and the original box/packaging could ensure that it comes with everything. For example, some years back, [a guy named Dan Budiac bought Apple IIc](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2537397/computer-hardware/sold-on-ebay--new-in-box-apple-ii--never-opened.html) [whose box had never been opened](https://www.flickr.com/photos/dansays/sets/72157603835099525/)!